# Remove Records From a Dumped SQL file

Tags: mysql, sql, linux

I have a dumped sql file named **my_dump.sql**.

Within that dump file there are various tables. I'm interested in the table named `foo_bars` which has a bunch of records. I would like to modify this sql file by doing the following:

- keep the `foo_bars` table structure, but remove all it's records from the sql file.

The outcome: when I create a new database via this sql file, It properly has the `foo_bars` table, but all the records are gone.

**Note**: I realize I *could* create a new database with all the `foo_bars` table records intact and then issue a `delete` statement once the database is created.  I do not want to do this though because there are tons of records.  I'd rather remove the records *beforehand* from the sql file.

How might I do this?

Comment: Simple, just edit out the INSERT section under where the Table Structure gets created. Then the table gets created and no data is loaded

Comment: Keep a copy of the original Dump file, in case you change your mind though :)

Comment: Can't you comment the `INSERT INTO foo_bars ( ......` ?

Comment: I think it will be better if you tell us what is your MySQL version and provide us with a snap of `INSERT ` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Do you still have access to the source MySQL instance where you got the dump file? You could create a new dump file with the `--no-data` option. That dumps the table definition without any INSERT statements following.

Another tricky alternative: edit your dump file and change the table options to add `ENGINE=BLACKHOLE` (replacing the existing engine option on that table, if there is one). Then all the following INSERT statements will be processed, but will result in no storage.

After you finish processing the dump file, run `ALTER TABLE foo_bars ENGINE=InnoDB;` to change the table back to InnoDB (or whatever engine you intend it to use, but I'd prefer InnoDB).

Read more about BLACKHOLE here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html

You haven't shown the table you want to handle in this way, so I can't guarantee that your table will be compatible with the blackhole engine. I can't think of any potential incompatibilities off the top of my head, but I haven't tried it so I can't be sure.

Comment: Nice solution with ENGINE=BLACKHOLE!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this method will help you, because as you said, all the records are gone.
Search the **my_dump.sql** file for all `INSERT INTO foo_bars` commands, and replace with `INSERT IGNORE INTO foo_bars`, so that all duplicate records are not inserted into your table.
Let me know if it worked

Comment: `ignore` simply ignores errors.  It does not mean ignore running the insert statement: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/

Answer (score 0):

I think Bill Karwin solution is the best and the fastest. You can also do:

Edit your dump file to add before inserting into `foo_bars`

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET autocommit = 0;
```

After the end of the last insert statement into `foo_bars`

```
ROLLBACK;
SET autocommit = 1;
```

You can read more about `autocommit` mode, `ROLLBACK` an transactions here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html

---

**If the dump it's too big to edit**, you can also drop the table and create it again, it's faster than deleting the records.

Comment: Yes, this is easy solution but it will consume time for inserting data and canceling it later. It is nearly equal to executing `DELETE FROM foo_bars` after restoring data. @Neil states that he don't like this approach.

Comment: I already stated that this is not the optimal solution, but for the sake of building a nice page of answers to a good question, I think it's ok!